# To allow crawling of all but a specific folder, do I need to include an empty disallow directive in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

If I want my website to be crawled, do I need an "empty" disallow?

Is there any difference between

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Disallow: /folder/
```

and

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /folder/
```

I have seen a *robots.txt* where the first option is used but I don´t understand why.

Comment: Your second example is correct providing you only intend to block /folder/.

Answer (score 2):

An empty disallow matches nothing and is ignored. The second example is what you're looking for.

> To allow all robots complete access
>
> ```
> User-agent: *
> Disallow:
> ```
>
> (or just create an empty "/robots.txt" file, or don't use one at all)

http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: It looks like he wants to allow all crawling except one specific folder

Comment: @Stephen This is true. That is why the second example works. The first two lines "allow all robots complete access" as shown in the quote.

Comment: Got it.  I thought you were trying to repeat his second option in the quote.